# How represent Routing in JMapViewer

Tags: java, dictionary, openstreetmap, jmap, jmapviewer

I use JMapViewer to draw the map in my java desktop application. I would know if exists some methods that I can use to draw the shortest path between to Point following the car path.

Answer (score 1):

JMapViewer covers map rendering with OpenStreetMap (OSM). For routing, you will have to use one of the [OSM libraries](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing#Libraries.2FDevelopment-Tools), for example the Apache-licensed, open-source **[GraphHopper](http://graphhopper.com/)**.